# How to break the line in Formula for a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, singleemailmessage, email-alert

I want to use this formula with merge fields in Send Email action by using the formula in the body of the email. However, I am not able to line break the text in formula.

Attached are the screenshots.
[image]

I tried using BR() but it does not work.

Any solutions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a new resource of type "Text Template" instead of Text. You will be able to insert whatever resources you need. This is actually a recommended way to build the body of the email.

Comment: Thank you , it worked